# Import error with Mapnik in Anaconda 2

Tags: python-2.7, mapnik, anaconda, importerror

I'm using Anaconda to write geographic programs, so I need to use packages like Mapnik.
After installing Mapnik in Anaconda2, it started to error. First about Mapnik itself and after do some actions now it's reached to this error:

```
from _mapnik import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I installed it with pip command in Anaconda command prompt with some minor errors.

My system: Windows 8.1 64 bit, Anaconda 2, Python 2.7, Mapnik 2.2.0

Comment: I've tracked some Q&A similar or related to my case beforehand but any could help to solve mine! I guess it may be something unique! So I created this thread hoping to solve my problem step by step...

Comment: In your folder anaconda environment, you have a folder "Lib" and in this folder you have a folder "site-packages" with all modules installed. Try to check the presence of the mapnik module.

Comment: Yes, I have two folders here named: 'mapnik' and 'mapnik-0.1.dist-info'. While the latter includes some files, the former (mapnik) includes two subfolders and a couple of files. The sub folders named: 'plugins' and '__pycache__'...

Comment: Try "import mapnik" instead of "import _mapnik"

Comment: I typed "import mapnik" at the first line of the code and got the above error! May I need to send my code here?!

Comment: The code will not be of much help, it's just the import of a module. If you have mapnik in your "site-packages" folder, the problem comes from your Python interpreter. You must use the Python located in your Conda environment.

Comment: Do you mean installing Mapnik using my conda prompt or anything else? Can you explain more...

Comment: You currently have at least 2 Python interpreters: the anaconda one and the native Python one. When you install a package, it is either installed on one or the other but not on both. If you installed the package with conda, mapnik is not installed for the native Python interpreter.

Comment: I tried "import mapnik" in both Anaconda2 and Python 2.7.13 (via Anaconda prompt) and both issued the same error "from _mapnik import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." 
So it seems Mapnik is installed on both itself but there is a problem loading one/some DLLs. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Check the prerequisites https://pypi.org/project/mapnik2/#installation

Comment: I'm sorry but the info seems too technical for me to understand clearly (Because I'm new in working with Mapnik). I'll appreciate if you can make things simpler for me...

Comment: I've never used mapnik either, but the modules work more or less the same way.

Comment: OK so let me to clarify my problems with the prerequisites! 1.I'm not sure about 'The mapnik-config utility'. 2. standart=standard? 3.'to handle the CFLAGS/LDFLAGS to find it, or use minitage'. 4.Does it mean 'mapnik2' is a prerequisite to install 'mapnik 2.2.0'?! 5.'pycairo / PIL in the PYTHONPATH somehow'. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I can't help you any more, I'm giving you some ideas to explore. We have to go to them.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I'm afraid it seems a serious problem for me...

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/mapnik2/#installation                       The info seems to be related to linux/unix OS. Any page for Windows can be helpful...